# gRPC generated code misses service implementation

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, grpc

Following the [tutorial](https://grpc.io/docs/languages/cpp/basics/) I successfully generated the code I expected with protocol buffers:

```
protoc service.proto --proto_path="../proto/" --cpp_out="../cxx/gen/" --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin`
```

The models are generated as usable classes without error, but the service implementation differs from the one described in the above tutorial. The proto file looks like this:

```proto
syntax = "proto3";
option cc_enable_arenas = true;
option cc_generic_services = true;

package my_package;

message Service_slot{...}

message Slot_status{...}

message Slot_request{...}

message Service_slot{...}

service My_service{
  rpc add_slot(Service_slot) returns (Slot_status) {}
  rpc update_slot(Service_slot) returns (Slot_status) {}
  rpc request_action(Slot_request) returns (Slot_status) {}
}
```

What I could identify as a service looks like this(in service.pb.h):

```cpp
class My_service: public ::google::protobuf::Service {
 protected:
  // This class should be treated as an abstract interface.
  inline My_service() {};
 public:
  virtual ~My_service();

  typedef My_service_Stub Stub;

  static const ::google::protobuf::ServiceDescriptor* descriptor();

  virtual void add_slot(::google::protobuf::RpcController* controller,
                       const ::my_package::Service_slot* request,
                       ::my_package::Slot_status* response,
                       ::google::protobuf::Closure* done);
  //... (others left out for clairty)
 private:
  GOOGLE_DISALLOW_EVIL_CONSTRUCTORS(My_service);
};
```

but it's nothing like what' described in the tutorial. Not even sure how to provide those arguments.
I've done this in Java, and there the server I implemented was based on a classname ending with `grpc`, but I found nothing like this here.

- What have I found, and how can I understand it? I believe this must be a base service implementation, and the actual server I need to implement is not here.
- Maybe I generated the proto files wrong? What can I do to correct it?

Comment: The grpc build is up to date with the latest at the time of the question.

Comment: According to [the options in the grpc repository](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/google/protobuf/descriptor.proto) , the option ` cc_generic_services ` should not be set to true. But if I remove it, no services are generated whatsoever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was missing the `--grpc_out="../cxx/gen"` argument.
With the command

```
protoc service.proto --proto_path="../proto/" --cpp_out="../cxx/gen/" --grpc_out="../cxx/gen --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=`which grpc_cpp_plugin`
```

The service code now generates into the `service.grpc.pb.cc` file.